# android - How to add satellte image in osmdroid

Tags: java, android, openstreetmap, osmdroid

I get a .png from my server that represents a satellite image and I would put this image like a layer over the OpenStreetMap so I can see the street (under the satellite image) and the aerial photo on the same map.

I use this method

```
    Drawable d = new BitmapDrawable(getResources(), bitmap);
    bb = map.getBoundingBox();

    Location SO = new Location(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
    SO.setLatitude(bb.getLonWest());
    SO.setLongitude(bb.getLatSouth());

    Location NO = new Location(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
    NO.setLatitude( bb.getLonWest());
    NO.setLongitude(bb.getLatNorth());

    Location NE = new Location(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
    NE.setLatitude(bb.getLonEast());
    NE.setLongitude(bb.getLatNorth());

    float height = SO.distanceTo(NO);
    float width = NE.distanceTo(NO);

    Projection projection = map.getProjection();
    int y = map.getHeight() / 2;
    int x = map.getWidth() / 2;
    GeoPoint geoPoint = (GeoPoint) projection.fromPixels(x, y);

    deleteLayers(GroundOverlay.class);
    GroundOverlay myGroundOverlay = new GroundOverlay();

    myGroundOverlay.setImage(d);
    myGroundOverlay.setPosition(geoPoint);
    myGroundOverlay.setDimensions(width*0.94f,  height*1.06f);
    map.getOverlays().add(myGroundOverlay);
    map.invalidate();
```

the problem is that the image always is stretch. my png cover only a part of my map (and it's ok beacuse our png is this way). When i move in the map the image stretching in all map but and it cover a part of map that it not rappresent.
Also, the image is not in the right place (look the red arrow).
[image]

How can i fix it?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your satellite image is limited to a portion of map you can use osmbonuspack GroundOverlay.

Comment: thanks for the comment, i think is the right way. i edited my question, can you help me?

Comment: can you help me?

Answer (score 0):

Probably this issue: https://github.com/MKergall/osmbonuspack/issues/273
Look at the hint about corrective coefficients.

Comment: i tried with that issue but now the image i too big, i have edit again the question with the new code @MKer

Comment: I don't see any corrective coefficient in your code, as mentionned in the issue 273, like: groundOverlay.setDimensions(width*0.94f, height*1.06f);

Comment: i tried but the result is the same, now i edited the post with the coefficient

Comment: LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, where is this? No way to reproduce and debug. Put a Marker on your center, a Marker at each expected corner.

Comment: And try to play with the coefficients.